# PHPmailer script runs without problems but doesn't send anything

Tags: php, phpmailer

I have a really simple PHP code for sending emails. The page is loading without any errors but it doesn't seem to do anything. 
also, I am new to PHP and I don't really know how to debug this stuff.
I'll really appreciate a little help (: thank you!

```
<?php
require_once('PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php');

$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->isSMTP();
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->SMTPSecure ='ssl';
$mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
$mail->port = '456';
$mail->isHtml();
$mail->Username = 'lagofbot@gmail.com';
$mail->Password = 'lago9876543s';
$mail->Subject = 'Hello';
$mail->Body = "test";
$mail->From = 'no-replay';
$mail->FromName = 'no-replay';
$mail->AddAddress('mrxvr123@gmail.com');
$mail->send();
?>
```

Comment: Try `$mail->SMTPDebug = SMTP::DEBUG_CONNECTION;` to output informations about connection and communication

Comment: Try debugging options https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/SMTP-Debugging

Answer (score 0):

change your code like this and see if it will show you any errors

```
$mail = new PHPMailer();
try {
$mail->isSMTP();
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->SMTPSecure ='ssl';
$mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
$mail->port = '456';
$mail->isHtml();
$mail->Username = 'lagofbot@gmail.com';
$mail->Password = 'lagofbot258258#258258';
$mail->Subject = 'Hello';
$mail->Body = "test";
$mail->From = 'no-replay';
$mail->FromName = 'no-replay';
$mail->AddAddress('mrxvr123@gmail.com');
$mail->send();
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: {$mail->ErrorInfo}";
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply!
it shows
 Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting

Answer (score 0):

Try with this

```
require __DIR__.'../phpmailer/src/PHPMailer.php'; //configure according your files
require __DIR__."./phpmailer/src/Exception.php";
require __DIR__."../phpmailer/src/SMTP.php";


$mail = new \PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer(); // create a new object
    $mail->isSMTP(); // enable SMTP
    $mail->SMTPDebug = 2; // debugging: 1 = errors and messages, 2 = messages only
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true; // authentication enabled
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl'; // secure transfer enabled REQUIRED for Gmail
    $mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
    $mail->Port = 465; // or 587
    $mail->Username = ""; //GMAIL ACCOUNT EMAIL ID
    $mail->Password = ""; // GMAIL ACCOUNT PASSWORD
    $mail->SetFrom("",''); // FROM THIS MAIL ID & SET AS DEFINE IN SECOND PARAMETER
    $mail->addAddress($email); // `TO` FIELD IN MAIL
    $mail->IsHTML(true);


    if (!$mail->Send()) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
```

And don't forget to enable less secure apps if you use gmail.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: I have enabled it but now it looks like I have another problem
it shows "Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting"

Comment: try to configure your php.ini and mail settings.